# Auhtorize.net (CIM) sample code not working with tomcat webapplication

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I have been trying to integrate Authorize.Net ( Customer Information Manager (CIM) )
I got their sample code [ wsimport -s /tmp/RebillAPI -p AuthNet.Rebill https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?wsdl ]
Their sample code works fine as stand-alone program, but not working in our tomcat web application. It throws an error below

Exception for getServiceSoap call:Could not initialize Service.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Service.
at org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.ServiceDelegate.(ServiceDelegate.java:77)
at org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:32)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:56)
at AuthNet.Rebill.Service.(Service.java:36)

Looks like they use CXF. and sample code is not compatible with Xfire.

Any thoughts how to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating the code from the WSDL yourself? If you keep the same packages as the sample code it should work (worst case - you will have to change some imports)

Answer (score 0):

Your Web service client must be using xfire jar and Web service server makes use of Jax-ws I have read somewhere that it may cause few issues try migrating your xfire to apache cxf jar.It might help I am also facing the same issue so trying out and after removal of xfire if I invoke the WS Client it works for me unfortunately removing jar is not an option for me.